# How to reuse ListFragement in given setup on some event

Tags: android

This what I have

1. XListActivity.class 
   It inflates LinearLayout and creates one Fragment, YListFragment
2. YListFragment.class
   Inflates LsitView from xml and setup a adapter which extends base adapter

Now on some event (e.g. onClick), I want to reuse same fragment and ListView whith different set of data.

If I handle OnClick() event in XListActivity then I don't have reference of ListView and Adapter created in yListFragment. I need them to empty adapter. I want to avoid static references.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your fragment by tag or id using the `FragmentManager`.

```
YListFragment fragment = (YListFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ylistfragment");
fragment.somePublicMethodInYListFragment();
```

Activity -> Fragment and Fragment -> Activity communication guidelines are outlined [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity)

Comment: Yes, this seems very neat at least better than static reference. Let me try this. Will update you. Thanks.